# Search domains by tags?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I do have 100k domains with with their related tags.

I want search domains by their tags. for example `google.com` domain is with `search,google,searchengine,engine,web,reference` tags

`bing.com` also with `search,bing,searchengine,engine,web` like this I have upto 100k domains with their related tags.

Criteria 1

If I search with tags say `search,google,searchengine,engine,web,reference` then the both domains `google.com` and `bing.com` should display in final result.

Criteria 2

If I search with tags `search,searchengine,engine,web` then also both domains `google.com` and `bing.com` should appear in results

Criteria 3

If I search with tags `search,searchengine` then also both domains should be displayed.

Criteria 4

If only tag `search` then also both domains need to be display.

Criteria 5

How do I prioritize result with its tag say if I search with tags `search,google,searchengine,engine,web,reference` then `google.com` should come first and `bing.com` come second

Finally to achieve all these results how should I design my table and how I should query to table?

Thanks

Comment: And you want us to code this for you?

Comment: I never asked a code...I asked table design and MySQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have at least two columns `domain_name varchar(400), tags text` -- you need to make sure all tags are comma separated.

Now, you make `tags` an index of type `FULLTEXT` to do full text search. See here for description. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

On a quick Google, there are many posts on utilizing MySQL text search to get relevant results sorted by relevance. (Hope this is what you wanted).

One such example is here http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/05/tags-with-mysql-fulltext.html It shows various ways to handle tag searches.